# Excel VBA - Timestamps for all Modifications to Rows in Multiple Tables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add timestamps for any modifications made to all rows in a table. I have been able to find/modify some code that will add the timestamp, but it does it for every cell in that column. As you can see it's got a line that tells it to start below a certain row. I want to make this apply only to the tables in each worksheet in my excel file. This would include any new tables added to the sheets. I'm very new to VBA, so any and all constructive help is welcome!

A little background: These sheets are being used for resource forecasting for my company for every different project we have going on. And every crew in each project has their own table. The forecasts get updated each week. I want to be able to quickly find what has changed when I get these at the end of the week. This isn't meant to be a permanent solution for our forecasting needs, but it will make my life easier in the meantime.

This is the code I've been working with. As I mentioned I know this only does part of what I want. I was trying to modify it to do what I want, but I just don’t have the know how yet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range, c As Range
Const DateStampColumn As Long = 2    
'Date stamp column number

For Each r In Target.Rows
    If r.Row > 10 Then
        For Each c In r.Cells
            If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cells(r.Row, DateStampColumn).Value = Date
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    End If
  Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the code to run whenever any cell in any table is changed? You'll need to use Intersect.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m after. How do I Implement that to only happen in tables, and to occur in all tables that may be added to the workbook? Please assume that I know nothing, because that’s about how new I am to this haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something along these lines I think. This checks whether Target is in a table,  I haven't added the Date as I'm not sure where it should go.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim t As ListObject

For Each t In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    If Not Intersect(Target, t.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell changed in " & t.Name
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next t

MsgBox "Cell changed not in any table"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That got me pointed in the right direction. I literally have spent all week trying to figure this out... See the answer I added for the modifications I made.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to modify it to do what I needed. I removed the message box lines because I think that will frustrate the users entering the data (I'm the one that has to extract it). There is one issue that I'm hoping you could help me solve. Whenever I add or delete a row within the tables a timestamp appears. Is there a way to keep that from happening? Here is what my code looks like currently:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim t As ListObject

For Each t In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    If Not Intersect(Target, t.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

         Application.EnableEvents = False
         Cells(Target.Row, "B").Value = Date
         Application.EnableEvents = True

        Exit Sub
    End If
Next t

End Sub
```